# How to validate multiple values at once and dose it need for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

I have the following express POST route handler that accepts GET and POST data something like this:

```
app.post('/handler/:id/:type', function (req, res, next) {
   var id = req.param('id');
   var type = req.param('type');

   var body = req.body;

   // Ho to check req.body params?
   var document = _.extend(req.body, {id: id, type: type});

   Collection.create(document, function (err, data) {
         .....
   })       
});
```

Is it problem to don't check incoming parameters and write to MongoDB database as in example above? Or how can check this ones?

Comment: If you don't care about the nature of the data being stored in your MongoDB database, then it's fine. Also, if someone could POST a HUGE document (>16MB), it would fail as it's too large for MongoDB. To validate -- check that the document is formed to your requirements. Is there more to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the question about possibility of xss using in MongoDB. I thing it's possible to save xss and the use in html code when user get comments list for example. What do you thing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your question. If you don't trust the client **fully**, then you must validate/scrub the data on the server before saving.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May you provide code snippet of your nodejs/express code where you get params from client and store them in MongoDB?

Comment: Maybe you should look at mongoosejs? You can define schmeas, do validatin, etc.